# Wordpress Post not getting updated in editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was building a custom plugin for one of my project and I am facing this issue with custom fields that I have created, but once I was trying to save the fields. I am not getting the data displayed in the admin editor. [screenshot of issue page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1PI3.png)

I am adding the code below Please find it.

```
<?php

function apt_add_fields_metabox()
{
    add_meta_box(
        'apt_college_fields',
        __('College Fields'),
        'apt_college_fields_callback',
        'college',
        'normal',
        'default'
    );
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes','apt_add_fields_metabox');

//Display Fields Metabox Content

function apt_college_fields_callback($post)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__),'wp_college_nonce');
    $apt_college_stored_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
    ?>
    <div class="wrap college-form">
        <div class="form-group">    
            <label for="issue_check"><?php esc_html_e('Issue Date Available','apt_domain'); ?></label>
            <select name="issue_check" id="issue_check">
                <?php 
                    $option_value = array('Yes','No');
                    foreach($option_value as $key => $value)
                        {
                            if($value == $apt_college_stored_meta['issue_check'][0])
                                { ?>
                                    <option selected><?php echo $value; ?></option>                                     
                            <?php
                                } 
                            else
                                { 
                            ?>
                                <option ><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                            <?php

                                }
                        }
                ?>
            </select>   
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="college-details"><?php esc_html_e('College Details','apt_domain'); ?></label>
            <?php 
                $content = get_post_meta($post->ID,'college-details',true);
                $editor = 'college-details';
                $settings = array(
                        'textarea_rows' => 5,
                        'media_buttons' => true
                    );

                wp_editor($content,$editor,$settings);
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="application_date"><?php esc_html_e('Application Available Date','apt_domain'); ?></label>
        <input type="date" name="application_date" id="application_date" value="<?php if(!empty($apt_college_stored_meta['application_date'])) echo esc_attr($apt_college_stored_meta['application_date'][0]);  ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function apt_college_save($post_id)
    {
        $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave($post_id);
        $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision($post_id);
        if(isset($_REQUEST['wp_college_nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['wp_college_nonce'],basename(__FILE__)))
            {
                $is_valid_nonce = true;
            }
        else
            {
                $is_valid_nonce = false;
            }   

        if($is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce)
            {                   
                return;
            }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['issue_check']))
            {
                update_post_meta($post_id,'issue_check',sanitize_text_field(['issue_check']));
            }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['college-details']))
            {
                update_post_meta($post_id,'college-details',sanitize_text_field(['college-details']));
            }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['application_date']))
            {
                update_post_meta($post_id,'application_date',sanitize_text_field(['application_date']));
            }           
    }

add_action('save_post','apt_college_save'); 
?>
```

Comment: Before posting, please check if the preview of your question looks OK or if you need to apply code formatting to your code, it'll make understanding your question easier for the audience.

Comment: okay ill make sure about the formatting next time...thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error with your code block.you missed out $_REQUEST['issue_check']

`update_post_meta($post_id,'issue_check',sanitize_text_field(['issue_check']));`

Corrected Code

`update_post_meta($post_id,'issue_check',sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['issue_check']));`